# Considered as duplication? Comment question vs Actual posted question

Tags: support, comments, questions

I am now getting used to SO and MSO.  But there is still something I want to know regards to comment and question posting, as well as duplication.
I am sure members/users in SO/MSO or who are in other type of forum browse through and see this posted question that is marked as 'Duplicate', often with a link to prove and show that his/her posted question is duplicated to someone else's question.
Posting same/similar question is a 'Duplicate' and I understand that.

But what if someone asked a same/similar question that was from a comment and that comment question had respectable amount of upvote?
Do we have privilege to brand that posted question as a 'Duplicate'? Or is this 'Duplicate' stamp only applies to same/similar question to another question?

Comment: Comments are second-class citizens. When they are deleted, they are gone forever (AFAIK).

Comment: @gunr2171 No, mods can see deleted comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions cannot be duplicates of a comment.  Comments are just little side notes to a post that either request further explanation or bring up some note of consequence, etc. The upvotes on a comment do not give a user any reputation points.  Comments are really meant to be minor things.

Many times I see someone ask a question in a comment, and the reply would be something like "You should try asking that as a question."  There would be no reason to close a question based on a duplicate comment.